# What is the behavior should be expected for the fix-up of EF Core Loading of Related Data

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm working on a read heavy api for the company and I'm validating the performance of each part on the reading flow. We utilize EF Core to interact with the database and most of our queries has eager loading enabled for fetching the related data. I take a look at the documentation and there is a quote in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) brings me confusion

> Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties
> to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context
> instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a
> navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or
> all of the related entities were previously loaded.

The quote only says EF Core will loaded automatically but doesn't indicate when it will expire, not even mentioning do devs have option to disable it. Such blackbox would makes me hard to consolidate the plan of improving the performance.  So if anyone could explain that it could be a huge help.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to worry about these words. It is all about ChangeTracker. If you load entity, navigation properties will be corrected if change tracker has related entities that already loaded in current context. There is no expiration, lifetime is controlled by the life of DBContext, which usually created per request.

Comment: What you can face with EF, which is critical for performance - cartesian explosion when using Eager Loading. Then you will have trouble.